# Characteristic subgroup of D$_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know D$_4$ have  8 elements and have 6 normal subgroups.  Among them trivial 2 normal subgroups is characteristic and Center is also characteristic.

I don't know remaining 3 normal subgroups are characteristic or not. If remaining are characteristic then why?

Can it be generalized?  I mean which normal subgroup of D$_n$ is normal,  can I say that?

Comment: The cyclic subgroup of order $4$ is characteristic because it is the only one. The other two normal subgroups are $C_2 \times C_2$ and are not characteristic becasue there is an automorphism that interchanges them (for example an automorphism induced by an inner automorphism of $D_8$). Yes this can all be generalized to arbitrary dihedral groups.

Comment: There are 3 subgroups of order 4,, so how can you say cyclic subgroup of order 4 is characteristic?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, one of the three subgroups is cyclic, and the the other two are not cyclic, so the cyclic one must be characteristic.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you mean "outer automorphism" in your first comment?

Comment: @verret no, I meant inner automorphism, but I was following the poster's conveniton, and so by $D_8$ I meant the dihedral group of order $16$. Conjugation by an element of $D_8 \setminus D_4$ induces an outer automorphis m of $D_4$ that interchanges the two $C_2^2$ subgroups.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't notice that he was using $D_4$ and you $D_8$.

Comment: I know there is only one cyclic subgroup of order 4, then how can you say that cyclic subgroup is characteristic ( if there only one subgroup of fixed order then that subgroup is characteristic)  but here there is 3 subgroup of order 4, then how can you say that cyclic subgroup of D$_4$ is characteristic?  Are you using another result to conclude that?

Comment: @Siraj If there is only one subgroup of a particular isomorphism type, it is clearly characteristic.

Comment: @verret  how?  Can you give me clue to prove this?

Comment: @Siraj you seem to know that if there is a unique subgroup of a given order, then it is characteristic. Think about why that it is true, it's essentially the same proof.